# Alamofire treat specific error codes

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My aim is to be able to catch whatever response in Alamofire requests (JSON, string) before my final competition handler is called and if it is a specific response code than I treat it the same for all responses.

I did a wrapper around Alamofire which let's me do specific requests I need (login request etc.) and there I catch the responses also, but I don't want to treat my error codes that are common globally in every specific request. It seems more naturally to just subclass Alamofire Request and make the treatment there.

But when I subclassed Alamofire Request class, in order for everything else to work I would also have to subclass Alamofire Manager and specifically override the method that returns the Request inside the manager.
And that is not possible because inside that method the superclass uses it's own private stuff.

How should I proceed in order to make a more clean and nice solution?

Comment: You have a valid question, but it's impossible to follow without you posting the code. You could also post pseudocode if that makes things a bit easiest to follow. I have some ideas, but I would really like to get a better understanding of your use case before I lay down a big architectural answer.

Comment: Thank you for offering support. I ended up having a wrapper around Alamofire with class methods for both types of "responses" I need in my app (responseWithString and responseWithJSON) in which I was catching the response and applying the filtering regarding error codes. So in my controllers I was just calling the methods from wrapper classes which cleared my responses from standard error codes.

Comment: Cool...I'm glad you got it figured out!