# Responding to Alamofire error codes

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Alamofire returns error code when performing requests like this

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
    .response {
        (request, response, data, error) in
```

Is there an easy way to use something like error.code to get out the error code out of the error string? Or will I have to wright an extension myself

BTW: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903053/alamofire-treat-specific-error-codes) and a lot of other questions, but found no answer yet.

Comment: What do you mean "error code"? You mean HTTP status code? That's `response.statusCode`. Otherwise, it's a property on `NSError`, the `error` argument.

Comment: You found any solution yet?

Comment: I went back using AFNetworking